# Google Calendar JSON API - Get Multiple Calendar Feeds

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-data-api

In an iOS application, I'm using the Google Calendar API to retrieve some public calendar events in JSON format by making a GET request to this URL.

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[feed_name]/public/full?alt=json
```

where [feed_name] is an ID identifying a specific public Google Calendar.

I have around 10 public Google calendars, whose events I need to display together in a list within my app. Currently, it seems like I'll have to make 10 GET requests and concatenate the results to achieve what I want.

Is there an alternative service endpoint to which I can provide a list of public Google Calendar IDs and I can get the concatenated list of events?

It seems to be possible to embed multiple public calendars together by adding multiple 'src' and 'color' parameters to the embed URL. But, how about getting multiple public calendars in JSON format through a web service?

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo pipe :) seems to be the only one I found so far. I've been looking to this now for a few days and couldn't get other solutions :(